# How do I squash a certain range of history in git? (Expert)

Tags: git

Been trying to figure this out for hours now but can't seem to find a solution.

So, let's say I have a repository like this: **A-B-C-D-E-F-G (master)** (the repository has many merges and thousands of commits so this is just for simplification).

I want it to become like so: **A*-F-G (master)**

Where A* is a squashed commit of A,B,C,D and E commits (around the first 2000 commits).

I've tried squashing the commits with interactive rebase but for some reason I get some weird errors like lines being already commented out with #, and "not applying" errors even though I make no changes. Also I get fewer commits in the interactive rebase than I count with git log? Why does that happen?

Anyways I'm doing this now:

```
git branch new-branch

git reset --hard E

git reset --soft A

git commit --amend
```

at which point I'm at **A*-** repository with one commit.

How do I go from here to add the **-F-G** commits that exist on the *new-branch* on the **A***?

Comment: `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`

Comment: Not going to work, cherry-pick is very iffy when it comes to merge commits, which I have a metric ton of. You could use -m to control the merges with cherry-pick, but I want to use the cherry-pick A..B range option, which f fails if you provide an -m flag or when you don't provide an -m flag too when you have merges in the range.

How would I rebase this when they have absolutely no similar parentage?

Comment: "*How would I rebase this when they have absolutely no similar parentage*" `git rebase --onto master branch~2 branch`

Comment: In the question title, what does "Expert" mean? By the way, in what follows "Anyways I'm doing this now", what you're doing is good.

Comment: @phd won't that just reapply B C D E over A* again and show up in the history?

Comment: It depends on what range you put into `new-branch~2 new-branch`. By careful selecting a short range you can apply only **F-G**.

Comment: This is a job for grafts and filter-branch, you're just rewiring ancestry not altering snapshot contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a collection of tools.

Which tools do you need to build a bookcase or bureau?  Perhaps a table saw, hammer, and nails would work, especially if you have some dado heads for the table saw to make nice groove joinery.  Or you could use some other kind of saws, a router for making joinery (dovetails!), a drill for pilot holes, screws, and a screwdriver.  Would that be better?

What if you want some fancy scroll-work on the front of your furniture?  Would you want a band saw, a jig saw, rasps, files?  Maybe a chisel?  Could you use a screwdriver as a chisel?

Git is a reasonably complete tool-set.  You can use any of the ones you like, as long as you get the end result you want.  Which ones make it *easiest* ... well, that depends on what you find easy.  If there are few commits to process, any of the various hand tools, such as `git rebase -i --root` or `git checkout --orphan` followed by particular operations would be fine.  Your example method is fine too: just cherry-pick the last two commits, using the old branch name to find them, then discard the old branch name if you don't want it any more.

Remember to update any tags you want updated, too.  Normally, it's a bad idea to update a tag, but you're basically telling everyone with a clone of the original repository to throw away their entire clone, in favor of this new one you're building—none of the commit hash IDs will match up at all; the new history is entirely unrelated to the original history.

The method [jthill describes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049263/how-do-i-squash-a-certain-range-of-history-in-git-expert#comment108006451_61049263) is a simple way to do the job too: insert a root graft, using `git replace`, at the point where you want to truncate history; then run `git filter-branch` with no filters (but with `--all --tag-name-filter cat`) to cement the graft into place permanently.  That's the power-tool approach.

Comment: When using filter-branch and the truncation is at a point where there are parallel branches, a subsequent merge will pull the old history.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment torek. I ran `git replace --graft <root> <truncate point>`, then running `git log --reverse` indeed shows the initial commit of the repo, then the 2nd commit is like the 1000th commit of the repo. Is it done then? How would I use the git filter-branch to "cement the graft"?

Comment: @torek running `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --all` does nothing, it just tells me how to use filter-branch and does nothing. (edit: I forgot to add the empty filters with `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` now it works. Let's see what this did though.

Comment: Done! Thanks so much for the guidance, git has so many different tools and commands I need to learn...

Comment: The issue with using `git replace` is that this *adds* a replacement object to the graph, keeping the original graph in place. Cloning the repository clones everything *except* replacement objects, so new clones see the old history, not the grafted history. Running filter-branch copies everything to a new graph based on the grafted history, so that there are no grafts any more. The new history (new set of commits) will now clone properly and the old history won't be visible at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for truncating the history described in the [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace) book. It lets you reassemble the history later if you need it for blame or bisect and leaves instructions in the root of the new history of how to do so.

#### Truncate history at `E`

1. Push `F` to history repo
2. ```
   $ echo 'Instructions to get the history...' | git commit-tree E^{tree}
   new root sha (R)
   ```
3. ```
   git rebase --onto R E
   ```

```
G <- master     rebase     G* <- master
|              -------->   |
F <- history               F*
|                          |
E                          R instructions
|
D
|
.
.
```

#### Restore history

1. Fetch history
2. ```
   git replace F* F
   ```

```
G* <- master
 \_____________
               \
     replace    \
F* ------------> F <- history
|                |
R instructions   E
                 |
                 D
                 |
                 .
                 .
```

Comment: This likely has the issue where if any conflicts were in history they would have to be re-resolved as git rebase applies commits one commit at a time...

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski You can use `git replace E R; git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat` instead of rebase.